# Manipulating instances of a class change the whole class

Tags: python-2.7, class, instance, instance-variables, self

So I'm struggling. I've seen quite a few posts on this topic, but after a couple hours struggling with the problem, I can't figure this out. Here are a few snippets of code I have. I'd like to be able to change one instance of the class without the other being changed as well, and I'm coming up short

```
class voter:
    def __init__(self, iPositon, jPosition, affiliation):
        self.affiliation = affiliation
        self.iPositon = iPositon
        self.jPosition = jPosition

class district:
    def __init__(self, *listOfVotersPassed):
        # super(district, self).__init__()
        self.listOfVoters = []
        for x in listOfVotersPassed:
            self.listOfVoters.append(x)     


class city:
    def __init__(self, *listOfDistrictsPassed):
        self.listOfDistricts = []
        for x in listOfDistrictsPassed:
            self.listOfDistricts.append(x)

def main():
    # I have a list  of class district that I pass to city()
    startCity = city(*startCityList)
    solutionCity = city(*solutionCityList)


    print solutionCity.listOfDistricts[0].listOfVoters[0].affiliation       # Democrat
    print startCity.listOfDistricts[0].listOfVoters[0].affiliation          # Democrat

    solutionCity.listOfDistricts[0].listOfVoters[0].affiliation = "Republican"

    print solutionCity.listOfDistricts[0].listOfVoters[0].affiliation       # Republican
    print startCity.listOfDistricts[0].listOfVoters[0].affiliation          # Republican



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

edit.
So I was asked about how I created the instance(s) of city. I have a file I'm reading in, each has either R or D in each line.

```
file = open(fileName)

# import contents
startVoterList = []
solutionVoterList = []

for line in file:
    for house in line:
        if " " in house:
            pass
        elif "\n" in house:
            pass
        else:
            startVoterList.append(house)
            solutionVoterList.append(house)
```

I also updated the classes, now each is in the following format. No changes besides the "(object)" after each class className.

```
class voter(object):
    def __init__(self, iPositon, jPosition, affiliation):
        self.affiliation = affiliation
        self.iPositon = iPositon
        self.jPosition = jPosition
```

Comment: Tip: if you're using Python 2.7, inherit from `object`. (Python 3 doesn't need to inherit from `object`.)

Comment: We don't see how `startCityList` and `solutionCityList` are created, but I suspect that your using the same voters (same list, same id) or districts to initialize your cities. Hence `solutionCity.listOfDistricts[0].listOfVoters[0]` is the same `voter()` as that in `startCity.listOfDistricts[0].listOfVoters[0]`.

Comment: I updated the question, @Evert. I thought that might be the issue too when I realized I had a problem, so I went back and read the file to two lists as shown, and kept them distinct from this point onwards. They share no variables, but are only located inside the same loops.

Comment: Nevermind, thank you @Evert. That was totally the issue. I had everything in separate lists until I fed districts to my city class. The names were similar and I just never looked at it properly. Thank you, you just saved my wall from a hole.